# SharePoint Online REST - The HTTP header ACCEPT is missing or its value is invalid

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am building an SPFX web part and trying to get data from a list using REST. Don't want all that noise returned so trying to use `odata=nometadata`.

I've read [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3628da8d-7aad-4ca6-901e-41ffe0c8f9cd/does-sharepoint-2013-support-applicationjson-accept-header-without-specifying-odataverbose?forum=appsforsharepoint) and [this](https://sympmarc.com/2016/05/02/making-your-rest-calls-simpler-by-changing-the-metadata-setting/) and plenty of other sites and was made aware that `Accept` header will not work without specifying `odata` value. The issue I am having is that my custom headers work with Postman, but not in code.

The following request works in Postman (don't mind the Content-Type, that was just a matter of testing):
[image]

Data is returned as expected. I've tried that will all `odata` values (`verbose`, `minimalmetadata`, and `nometadata`)

I am trying to use the same `Accept` header in code but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
const userResponses: Promise<SPHttpClientResponse>[] = [];  
const opt: ISPHttpClientBatchOptions = { headers: { 'Accept':'application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;'} }; 
const getUsers: Promise<SPHttpClientResponse> = spBatch.get(`${this._currentWebUrl}/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('${encodeURIComponent(list)}')/items?$select=User/Id,User/Title,User/Name,User/EMail,Manager/Title&$expand=User,Manager`,SPHttpClientBatch.configurations.v1, opt);  
userResponses.push(getUsers);
```

And this is what I get:
[image]

Does anyone know what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SharePoint Framework's http client internally uses the OData JSON format version 4.

So, in case of SPFx you need to modify it to use the format as `odata.metadata=minimal`.

In case you want verbose mode, change it as `odata.metadata=full` and if you only want the data and no extra metadata change it `odata.metadata=none`

Modify your code as below:

```
const userResponses: Promise<SPHttpClientResponse>[] = [];  
const opt: ISPHttpClientBatchOptions = { 
        headers: { 'Accept':'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal'} 
    }; 
const getUsers: Promise<SPHttpClientResponse> = spBatch.get(`${this._currentWebUrl}/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('${encodeURIComponent(list)}')/items?$select=User/Id,User/Title,User/Name,User/EMail,Manager/Title&$expand=User,Manager`,SPHttpClientBatch.configurations.v1, opt);  
userResponses.push(getUsers);
```

Having said that, if you want to keep using OData format 3, then you need to explicitly specify it as below by leaving it blank:

```
const userResponses: Promise<SPHttpClientResponse>[] = [];  
const opt: ISPHttpClientBatchOptions = { 
        headers: { 
            'Accept':'application/json;odata=nometadata',
            'odata-version': ''
        } 
    }; 
const getUsers: Promise<SPHttpClientResponse> = spBatch.get(`${this._currentWebUrl}/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('${encodeURIComponent(list)}')/items?$select=User/Id,User/Title,User/Name,User/EMail,Manager/Title&$expand=User,Manager`,SPHttpClientBatch.configurations.v1, opt);  
userResponses.push(getUsers);
```

Comment: Thanks. `odata.metadata=none` works fine. I couldn't get it to work using V3. After RTFM I tried using `'DataServiceVersion':'3.0'`, `'odata-version': ''`, and `'odata-version': '3.0'`, but without any luck.

Comment: True that, looks like a buggy client. Any way SPHttpBatchClient is in preview, so looks like this expected.  Would suggest that you open an issue in the issue list - https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues  and hope MS picks it up and fixes it